# CSS - Tableless Menu Bar on fluid layout and centered

Tags: html, css, css-tables

I am trying to make a tableless menu bar using some png images with transparencies. The menu bar is nested inside a wrapper with min/max widths and centers itself using auto left/right margins. Ideally I'd like 1 section to adjust itself length wise with a background repeat-x. Since the png's have transparency value they cannot overlap each other as that would increase the visibility on the overlapping sections.

I tried absolute positioning but that forces you to have a horizontal starting location which is unavailable in the fluid layout. Wrapper style:

```
margin-left: auto; 
margin-right: auto; 
min-width: 960px; 
max-width: 1260px; 
padding: 0px 20px 0px 20px; 
overflow: visible;
```

Working design with tables: http://jsfiddle.net/f35UK/

Images (I used base64 in the code but just in case):

- https://i.stack.imgur.com/0r4Qu.png main sprite
- https://i.stack.imgur.com/z6vxo.png
- https://i.stack.imgur.com/e1Yge.png

Answer (score 0):

use list items for your menu. 
for an example on how to set this you can view a project i am currenly working on:

http://basenharald.nl/3d/ 
in the source search for "navigatie" below that you will find the UL navigation

also open http://basenharald.nl/3d/css/style.css
in the source search for "#nav". This is the css part to set the navigation.

Comment: Not very helpful since you have a a fixed width #nav ul { width: 960px; }. Yes the menu inside will be a ul. The opposite side is the search form.